# owlcarousel not working in custom template

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

I called the owlcarousel in the main.js and it is like that---

```js
(function($){
    
    "use strict";
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        
        $(".homepage-slides").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            nav:true,
            dots: flase,
            autoplay:flase,
            loop:true,
        });
        
    });
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        
        
    });
    
    
}(jQuery));
```

Owlcarousel creating problem not working right way in my custom template. It is console error.

Please check the link-- 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e590yzb1w27ae4q/BasicTemplate.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `false` as `flase`. Change it correctly to `false` and it will work.